# Can't escape curly braces in \lstinline

Tags: errors, listings, braces

Upon trying to typeset the following TeX I get the **error**:

> Too many }'s. ...handleClick } >Button component}

**TeX**:

```
\lstinline{<Button onClick=\{this.handleClick\}>Button component</Button>}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Using  curly braces for the source code argument of `\lstinline` is marked as experimental in the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf) of package `listings`. The normal form with a character to delimit the argument works without the need to escape braces inside the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\lstinline|<Button onClick={this.handleClick}>Button component</Button>|
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

---

The expression

```
\lstinline{<Button onClick=\{this.handleClick\}>Button component</Button>}
```

with or without the backslash does not work, because the source code argument is scanned in a special way as verbatim with changed category codes. The first `}` ends the argument: `<Button onClick=\{this.handleClick\` the remaining part `>Button component</Button>}` is set outside of `\lstinline` and the closing curly brace without counterpart causes the error.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed response.  It works great.

Comment: Had the exact same Problem, thanks for your super simple solution!

Comment: Syntax: `\lstinline[⟨key=value list⟩]⟨character⟩⟨source code⟩⟨same character⟩`

Comment: I'm trying to do a shell line that has sed and awk in a pipeline, so the | does not work.  But the answer is great and thanks to Marc's comment I was able to use I (uppercase i) which did not appear elsewhere in the pipe.  Unfortunately I still don't know how to deal with a $ sign: quoting it leaves the \, and not quoting it enters math mode...

Comment: @markgalassi Maybe you have activated `mathescape`. Then, it can be disabled for a `\lstinline` by using the optional argument: `\lstinline[mathescape=false]I<shell pipeline>I`